# Prefect is not registering flow when call flow.register() . It triggers can´t pickle error

Tags: python, prefect

Using Prefect to register the workflow with my backend server returns this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/usr/Documents/Test_Automation/Automation/qa-automation/date_validator_Prefect/date_validator.py", line 114, in 
> flow.register(project_name="QA-Test")
> File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/core/flow.py", line 1726, in register
> registered_flow = client.register(
> File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/client/client.py", line 848, in register
> serialized_flow = flow.serialize(build=build)  # type: Any
> File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/core/flow.py", line 1507, in serialize
> self.storage.add_flow(self)
> File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/storage/local.py", line 143, in add_flow
> f.write(flow_to_bytes_pickle(flow))
> File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/utilities/storage.py", line 178, in flow_to_bytes_pickle
> cloudpickle.dumps(flow, protocol=4), newline=False
> File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 73, in dumps
> cp.dump(obj)
> File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 633, in dump
> return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
> TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object

It only happens when I try to `flow.register(project="QA-test")`.
If I only add `flow.run()` it works fine.

This is the beggining of the code:

```
@task(name="T3")
def feed_validator():
    jsonpath = ''
    results = []
    urlsData = load_data('urls2.json')
    for feed in urlsData:
        for country in feed["countries"]:
            feedUrl = feed['url']
            if feed['type'] == 'Availability':
                feedUrl = feedUrl.replace('/us/', "/" + country.lower() + "/")
            feedData = getFeed(feedUrl)
            feedDateInfo = isFeedUpdated(feedData)
            if feed['network'] == 'network-samp(gate)':
                feed['network'] = 'network-samp'
            elif feed['network'] == 'network-samp(samp)':
                feed['network'] = 'network-samp2'
                country = ''
            elif feed['network'] == 'network-samp3(samp3)':
                feed['network'] = 'network-samp3'
                country = ''
            elif feed['type'] == 'Catalog':
                country = ''
            results.append((feed['platform'], feed['type'], feed['network'], country, feedDateInfo[1]))
    orderedResults = multisort(list(results), ((4, False), (1, False), (2, False), (3, False)))
    report = email_sender.createResultsEmail(orderedResults)
    email_sender.sendEmail(report.as_string())

with Flow("test", storage=Local()) as flow:
    feed_validator()

flow.register(project_name="QA-Test")
flow.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Local storage, Prefect by default uses pickled flow. You can switch to using script storage, as described on [this Documentation page](https://docs.prefect.io/orchestration/flow_config/storage.html#pickle-vs-script-based-storage)

Comment: Is this same error possible with Docker storage?

Comment: it might be easier to ask this in community Slack and explain your use case in more detail prefect.io/slack